# Adding string with new line characters in a file to upload to an SQL UTF8 database

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, end-of-line

I've discovered the `\copy` command to upload CSV/TSV files to a table. It's a very convenient method because I have a large amount of data to load at the same time.

My problem is that I have some text to load and some of them contain `\n` characters. Because I generate utf-8 text files, they are recognized as new line characters and can't be properly loaded in the database. Is there a way to encode them, using python function, to create my file to upload ?

Comment: Your file must match the CSV requirements if you would like to import it using CSV mode. Carriage Return is often defined as Row Separator. If it appears in a Columns, it must be escaped or enclosed into a cell quoting. Does the producer of your file can handle this and delivers quoted strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the `\n` I've used the python str `replace` method when creating my TSV file.

I replace `\n` by `\\\\n`. This method gives me some `\\n` in my TSV files and, because the postgreSQL insertion from the file interpret the special characters, `\\n` is stored as `\n` in the database.

So :

```
my_usable_string = my_string.replace("\n", "\\\\n")
```